# google share doesn't show description while sharing

Tags: google-plus

I have a google plus share button in my website but it doesn't load any description on it. I have even tried adding

```
<meta property="og:title" content="titletest"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="url of image"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="descriptiopnddd fas"/>
```

I don't understand why it only shows the site *"onlyin.projectsshowcase.info"*.

I just want to show default title, description and image while anyone clicks on share button on the page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Google+ stream design no longer uses the shared page's description in regular shares.

Comment: Why then do "share" links for Google+ on some sites still show description in the share dialog? For example, http://www.voanews.com/ or http://well-spent.com/ both do, but my attempts (same URL, same meta tags) don't.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to share a specific url with a description you can use the code below.

As far as I'm aware sharing via the "plus.google.com/share?url=[Your URL]" method only allows a title, image and url.

Here's a link to some documentation that may help you:

```
[Google share documentation][1]
```

**Share method with description:**

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<g:plus action="share"></g:plus>
```

Comment: My experience of using the non-script approach supports your claim that it does not allow the use of a description but I can't find it documented anywhere.